# Django work with "dictionary" table

Tags: django, django-forms

I have some misunderstanding with django form and layouts.
I have a dictionary-style table looks like this:

```
class Ministry(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length='128', null=True)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length='128', null=True)
    tip = models.TextField()
```

Due to this table I have a straight dictionary-style dependencies between category and sub-category. And I want to use this on form like a dropdown list.
But I can't understand, how I can take two fields separately on form?
I use this variation:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.category + " " + self.sub_category
```

And on the form I have only one dropdown list looks like this:

```
<select id="id_category" name="category">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="9">IMAGES Photography</option>
    <option value="11">IMAGES Digital Art</option>
    <option value="12">IMAGES Typography and Layouts</option>
    ..........
```

I undestand, that for autocomplete this two dropdowns I need to use jQuery or whatever. But I can't believe, that django doesn't have a simple way to separate this two columns.
At the end I need to choose category (ex. IMAGES), choose sub-category after(ex. Digital Art) and after that pass value "11" through the "id_category" field on the form.
And one more thing: when I have a final post and I'm trying to shown only category on template, I still have "IMAGES Digital Art", but I need only "IMAGES". And I know, that's because I try to return category + sub_category.

Could you please give me an advice how I can work with this two columns separatly?

**EDIT:**

To clarify my needs, I want to have only one table with straight dependencies and two dropdown lists on the form.

Comment: Don't specify `null=True` in CharField https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#null

Comment: Ususally value of `max_length` is `int`, thus specify `max_length=128`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Ministry(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    tip = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.category.name, self.sub_category)
```

Comment: This is a good solution but in this way I'll have two tables and one dropdown, but I want one table with straight dependencies between category and sub category and two dropdowns on form